# Load from text file at program startup

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Sorry for the likely noobish question, just starting to learn c#, and couldn't find anything that worked.

I'm making a text editor in c#, and so far it can open and save text files from inside the program with dialogs, but how can I make it load the text from a file that I open in windows explorer, outside of the editor, with the editor

Basically, I can already read from text files opened inside the editor, but how can i make it so that if I open a text file (and have the default program for opening text files set to my editor), it'll read it?

I saw something about getting the filename somehow and passing it as an argument, if that helps.

Comment: There's a Main method. That method is called to start the application. It's passed all the command-line/shell arguments, if any. Check if there's one, if so treat it like a filename and try to open it like you do any other file.

Comment: @David: No. The question is fairly clear. It's vague only insofar as Serdnad doesn't know how to accomplish what he wants (needs a boost in the right direction).

Comment: Are you asking about how to create file association (so, when one will click on the file in Explorer, it will start your application), or about how to process file associations in your application, or both of these questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to pass the filename/names as command line arguments ?

If you look at the `Main`, which starts the program you can see that it will store parameters in a `string[]` (string array) so if you pass arguments you can just check the `args[]` inside the program to get the parameters you sent in. Please ask more if you need more help !

---

**UPDATED**

As per your request if you open a file from windows explorer it will send the path of the file it to the Main method. So lets say you right click a file and choose to open it with your text editor. You have to use the path as I do below, and read the file's content. Then you can do whatever you want with the content.

```java
class TestClass {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Now you have all arguments in the string array
        if (args.Length != 0) {
            string pathToTextfile = args[0];
        }

        StreamReader textFile = new StreamReader(pathToTextfile);
        string fileContents = textFile.ReadToEnd();
        textFile.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks about right, i had tried something similiar to this, but got an error, but I'm not getting it any more.

Comment: I should work now you only need to add what you want to do with the contents!

Comment: Ok, thanks, i think I got it, I'm implementing it right now, and will let you know if it works

Comment: Thanks so much, and thanks to everyone who helped. And i promise the next question will be better done :).

Comment: Er, follow up question, I've been trying to get this to work, but I can't, and I'm pretty sure I did everything right. My new problem is that `args[0]` is always the editor's path, and not the file's path. Do you think you can help? Oh, and also, the way i ended up having it is that I use `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` in form1.cs, and then read the file, incase that means anything.

Comment: Update: I don't mind providing any code if you need, just ask for it, and I could give you the project, or files you need. I don't really mind, considering you could find just about the same thing on google in 10 seconds...

Comment: Yeah, and I had been getting an exception, but I just tried it again, and I really wonder what I had been doing before, because look at that, it's working... Well, thanks for your help again

Answer (score 1):

So you have a text editor coded in C#, and you want to be able to open a text file through double clicking on the file in Windows explorer. If so, basically 2 steps:
 1. Your editor program must accept one argument as the file name. Carl had already given an example.
 2. You need to associate *.txt files with your text editor. This could be done through editing Windows registry. please check [What registry keys are responsible for file extension association](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OpenFileDialog` class to select a file to show in your program.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant is, my program can already do this, but if i double click on file, my editor will open as it should, but it won't load the file, and this is what I'm looking for.